# How to fix array after separate?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Creating a cabinet. I have created a cabinet and array. I want to separate the door with array. As show below. When i select the door and hit separate the door loose the alignment. I have to adjust manually to fix the door. Any way to fix the door with array align after separating. Thanks

[Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se68o.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use **constant offset** in the array modifier.
[image]